# How to make Ipopt work with GAMS on Windows

Tags: nlp, gams-math, ipopt

I am trying to use Ipopt solver to solve a NLP problem. The problem is programmed in GAMS on win10 system (64 bit). I try to download and install Ipopt solver as well as GAMSlinks, and then the solver can be tested in GAMS with the command,

```
Option NLP = MyIpopt;
```

I follow the three links to install MSYS2. Coinbrew is installed, in which Ipopt folder is added; and GAMSlinks is installed as well.

```
https://coin-or.github.io/user_introduction.html#os-x 
https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt
https://github.com/coin-or/GAMSlinks
```

However, when I run the GAMS code, error message was reported.

```
Unknown algorithm
The GAMS statement 'option subsystems;'" will list the installed subsystems in teh GAMS listing file.
```

I am new to this area, and have no idea on what is the exact issue here and how to solve it. Please give me some help. (If the post is not specific enough, please let me what I should add as well.)

Comment: Why don't you just use the Ipopt version that comes with GAMS (`Option NLP = Ipopt;`)

Comment: It's a stupid question. Thanks. I tried the Ipopt solver. It performs much worse than Conopt4. Not sure how it will perform with additional option settings. Any suggestions to solve NLP problem with bilinear constraints? And it seems that GAMS offers the option to use external Ipopt solver. How can I solve the problem in this post?

Comment: The "Unknown algorithm" error message indicates a problem with the installation of your own solver (step 2 of the installation described at https://github.com/coin-or/GAMSlinks). However, without more information how you did that, it will be hard to help (and I might not be the right one to help with this problem anyway, sorry).

Comment: Yeah I feel that's the hardest part. It is not clearly described, to me at least. Thanks anyway!